# SQL questions for Stock Market App

Tags: sql-server, azure, sqldatatypes, database-normalization

I'm creating a stock market app using SQL Server (Azure) stored procedures. I've read extensively on the following issues but am still undecided so would appreciate feedback:

1. Prices in `Money` or `Decimal(9, 2)` or `Integer` (requiring `*` or `/ 100`)?
   Note: apparently the Australian stock market uses integers for better performance AND when I import seed data from excel into a money datatype it erroneously created a value for the third digit after the decimal point BUT as much as some people hate money datatype it is easier for development at least
2. I have a `BuyOrders` and a `SellOrders` table that when matched creates a row in a `Contracts` table. These tables COULD be **normalized** such that the `Contracts` table contains only the `BuyOrderID` and `SellOrderID` BUT it seems to me that extra security (i.e. tracking) is worth the negligible performance cost to duplicate write certain columns in the `Contracts` table (i.e. `StockSymbol`, `MemberID`).

Comment: Consideration for integers: how many implied decimal places you want to store? How would you handle totals e.g. total stock value could be a very large number? How would you handle analytical calculations which often require numbers with high scale. Keep in mind that a lot of existing large enterprise software was initially created decades ago when hardware and available tool set was very different.

Comment: This question will only get you opinions and discussions. It's really broad with no single right answer. Off topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: David Makogon:  I'm not being snarky in asking this but can you suggest a better place to post such questions?

Answer (score 2):

At first, you have to get precision requirements from the business, but you'd consider at least four digits after decimal point. When you trade international stocks there are crazy exchange rates are involved. Also, when you start to calculate portfolio's performance you'll get a lot of decimals
Then you have to consider the biggest possible portfolio value as about 100K Billions. You also do not want to be impacted by unpredictable inflation.

If your customer is fine with 4 digits precision, you are OK with "**MONEY**" data type. That is only 8 bytes. 
If, by some reason, they want better precision you go with DECIMAL(p,s), which might be up 13 bytes, but in case of small numbers it will use only 5 bytes.